# How to resolve graphics corruption on Street View when using Google Earth?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, google-earth

When I go into Street View on Google Earth and use the arrow keys to move around, the graphics become corrupted (distorted). Please see these examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using XP Home SP 3, Google Earth 6.0.3.2197 and graphics card NVIDIA GeForce 6100 nForce 405, with latest NVIDIA drivers (275.33).

Is there any way to resolve this, as this problem is making navigation in Street View impractical?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues on numerous computers with various configurations, so it's entirely a Google created problem. One thing is for sure, I've been using street view from the beginning and have never seen this until sometime in mid-2011, so my guess is that google has tried to optimize their photo database to lower quality and optimize size and load times for bandwidth, which in the end resulted in this problem. Doubt they will ever fix it now, although maybe they will as this can truly be a huge annoyance when you really want to check out certain places/residences and they're all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about this distortion it's in the photographs that Google are presenting to you.

I *think* it's caused by the fact that the camera car is moving as the panoramic photographs are taken.